# Is Phantom Steed considered a Familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, warlock, familiars

If I already have Find Familiar from Pact of Chain cast, does it become the *phantom steed* when I cast that spell?
Since I can't have two familiars, I want to see if *phantom steed* was defined as a one.

There is an [ethereal archetype homebrew at D&D beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/subclasses/3332-the-ethereal) I came across that offers the *phantom steed* spell.

Comment: @Parkruckus Thanks for clarifying the source. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, the Phantom Steed isn't a familiar

The spell *phantom steed* is a from the illusion school (PHB. p. 265), while *find familiar* is from the conjuration school.  No phrasing in *phantom steed*'s  descriptive text refer to familiars, summoning a spirit in "X" form, or replacing a familiar with the phantom steed if you already have a familiar.

What the spell does is provide a magical steed for an hour.  The steed can coexist with your familiar just fine.

[The homebrew you linked to](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/subclasses/3332-the-ethereal) makes no mention of the Pact of the Chain feature being influenced by bonus spells, or other patron features.

Comment: Solid answer, much appreciated. One step closer, back to work!

Comment: @Parkruckus Glad to be of help. Feel free to accept the answer, or wait for a better one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the answer by KorvinStarmast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122470/42805), I've also checked the entry of *Phantom Steed* in the Monster Manual: it doesn't have one. The spell description of *Phantom Steed* on Player's Handbook p.265 refers to *Riding Horse* on MM p.336 for its stat block (with the exception of a difference in speed). I took a look there, because sometimes a creature's entry offers optional ruling regarding allowing it as a familiar, as is the case with the imp and pseudodragon. It didn't offer any, therefore it cannot be a familiar by RAW.

Note: all additional options for familiars seem to be mostly tiny creatures (and some small ones), as are the beasts mentioned in the *Find Familiar* spell (PHB p.240).

> You gain the service of **a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form you choose**: bat, cat, crab, frog (toad), hawk, lizard, octopus, owl, poisonous snake, fish (quipper), rat, raven, sea horse, spider, or weasel. Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of a beast.

From a game balancing perspective it would make sense if only those sizes could be a familiar. Through that reasoning a large creature as *Phantom Steed* (Riding Horse) would be excluded. The spell description, however, doesn't mention this limitation to "tiny creatures" explicitly.